# How to set different overflow options with dropdown in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I want to set overflow property as ellipsis when the value is shown in dropdown, but want to fully display it when the dropdown list appears. Right now, when I am setting my property to ellipsis, both list items and the selected value that is shown are getting overflow as ellipsis.

Code:

```
Expanded(
                          child: DropdownButtonFormField<SubjectDatum>(
                              isExpanded: true,
                              items: (_subjectResponse != null
                                      ? _subjectResponse!.data
                                      : [])!
                                  .map((e) => e)
                                  .toList()
                                  .map((value) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem<SubjectDatum>(
                                  value: value,
                                  child: Text('adbhewuduewbfwewufvhweofvberufbvrefuohfbhef', overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),//Text(value.subjectSubjectName!, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                              hint: Text(
                                'Subject',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  color: const Color(0xFF1C1B1F)
                                      .withOpacity(.74),
                                ),
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                color:
                                    const Color(0xFF1C1B1F).withOpacity(.74),
                              ),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  color: const Color(0xFF1C1B1F)
                                      .withOpacity(.74),
                                ),
                                labelText: 'Subject',
                                floatingLabelAlignment:
                                    FloatingLabelAlignment.start,
                                border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                ),
                              ),
                              value: _selectedSubject,
                              onChanged: (item) {
                                setState(() async {
                                  _selectedSubject = item;
                                  _selectedUsers = null;
                                  await _activityServices
                                      .getAllUsers(
                                    sectionId: _selectedGrade.id,
                                    subjectId: _selectedSubject.subjectId,
                                  )
                                      .then((value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _selectedUsers = value!;
                                    });
                                  });
                                });
                              }),
                        ),
```

I tried to set overflow to visible, but it resulted in showing text visible both in list and the selected value too. You can see the images:

I want this to be ellipsis:

image of selected value

[image]

Not in the list:

image of dropdown list

[image]